# OSX 10.6 goes unresponsive

Tags: macos, command-line, crash

This behavior continues to perplex me. My MBP, running 10.6.7, *stops responding to all Apple-based software*. Whatever software I have open remains open (Terminal, iTunes, Safari), but if I try to use the F-shortcuts or launch any OSX-based software not already open (System Preferences for example) it just bounces in the dock then never launches.

I also cannot reboot without hard rebooting.

I left terminal open, so I see the following in `/var/log/system.log`

```
Jun 25 19:39:02 mjb-2 com.apple.ReportCrash.Root[59432]: 2011-06-25 19:39:02.585 ReportCrash[59432:7f1f] Saved crash report for CoreServicesUIAgent[59576] version ??? (???) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/CoreServicesUIAgent_2011-06-25-193902_localhost.crash
Jun 25 19:39:02 mjb-2 com.apple.ReportCrash.Root[59432]: 2011-06-25 19:39:02.586 ReportCrash[59432:b10f] Saved crash report for quicklookd[59571] version ??? (???) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/quicklookd_2011-06-25-193902_localhost.crash
```

Comment: Have you tried repairing the disk via the Mac OS X install DVD?

Comment: Yes - I've repaired / corrected permissions from DVD. This still occurs. Note: it only happens when I put the system to sleep multiple times... that's part of the interesting behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're handy with the Terminal, try using `sudo syslog` to see all messages in the syslog database, regardless of what text log they may or may not have gotten written to.

Also look in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` for crash, hang, and spin reports.

The `sample` and `spindump` commands are your friends as well, as is `top`.

Gather some of that information and paste it in here (or link from here to pastebin or a github gist) and give us a crack at figuring it out for you.

(Don't post the whole output of `sudo syslog` -- it likely goes back a long, long time. Just do the stuff from around the last time it happened.)

**Update:**
If the timestamps on those crash logs you mentioned happen to correspond to when the problem is happening, don't forget to post those as well.

Also, here are two other SuperUser Questions with similar symptoms. Maybe look these over and see if you're hitting the same things (you don't happen to be running Mozy or "Hands Off!", do you?), or if you can glean troubleshooting tips from these.

[Some Mac applications crash frequently, with "__THE_SYSTEM_HAS_NO_PORT_SETS_AVAILABLE__" in backtrace](https://superuser.com/questions/232547/some-mac-applications-crash-frequently-with-the-system-has-no-port-sets-avail)

[Getting console message: ipc_kmsg_copyout_header: can't grow user ipc space. Any Mac OS X kernel gurus in here?](https://superuser.com/questions/294285/getting-console-message-ipc-kmsg-copyout-header-cant-grow-user-ipc-space-any)

Comment: I should have read the parenthesis first... terminal went _nuts_ with syslog output :) More info to come!

Comment: ok, `spindump` is the coolest command I've learned in a while. Voting up for that beautiful output.

Comment: It happened again! I ran `spindump` and `syslog` and then looked with top and found a `pid` and `kill`ed it. Results? System shutdown. I saved files to /tmp too so I've got nothing. Balls balls balls. More to come...

Comment: @mjb It would be interesting to know the name (not just pid) of the process you killed. For example launchd and WindowServer are probably not the best processes to arbitrarily kill... :-)

Comment: It was #38 - I think WindowServer. The premise was that it could be some sort of virus-bound service, but in actually it was a lesson on OSX system architecture :)

Comment: @mjb Those two crash files you mentioned -- do the times of those crashes correspond to when you saw the system go unresponsive? If so, then update your Question with the text of those crash reports (or link to them on pastebin.com or gist.github.com). They may contain clues we can analyze for what's going on.

Comment: @mjb For example, I was able to help [this guy](http://superuser.com/questions/232547/some-mac-applications-crash-frequently-with-the-system-has-no-port-sets-avail) figure out his problem by looking at his crash reports. Maybe you're hitting something similar.

Comment: @mjb By the way, are you running either Mozy or "Hands Off!"? Here's a report of someone with similar symptoms: http://superuser.com/questions/294285/getting-console-message-ipc-kmsg-copyout-header-cant-grow-user-ipc-space-any

Comment: I can no longer repeat the issue... so either something I removed or updated or something did the trick. Still no root cause but I appreciate your great comments!